# Use mutiple gift cards towards same purchase online

Tags: gift-card

Let us say I have 2 walmart gift cards , each for 10$. Now if I go to walmart and buy a 20 $ item (before tax), then I can give the 2 gift cards one after another and that will cover the cost.

Now when buying online, is the same true?  Usually on the checkout page, I just see one text box for discount-code(which i assume is the gift card code). So does it mean that I can only use one card?

Comment: Are you asking about Walmart specifically?  In general this is a feature that some sites may support and others may not.

Comment: Discount code has nothing to do with gift cards. It is more like an online coupon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each website has different limits for the number of coupons, gift certificates, and payment cards they will accept for a single transaction.

Some websites allow you to merge gift cards into a single bucket; Starbucks and iTunes some to mind.

The only way to see is to try and add multiple. I have seen sites that when you enter the first card number it puts it in a list and allows for you to add a another card with no indication what the limit is.